# How to use es6 imports within an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to break up a giant JavaScript file into smaller files for easier maintainability. It looks something like this:

```
(function($, document, window) {
  var $htmlBody = $("html, body"),
    $body = $("body"),
    $doc = $(document),
    $loc = $(location),
    $win = $(window);


  // THOUSANDS OF LINES OF CODE HERE...


  $doc.ready(function() {
    APP.init();
  });
})(jQuery, document, window);
```

I moved all the code out into separate files and replaced each block of code with an import to that file, now the huge JS file looks like this:

```
(function($, document, window) {
  var $htmlBody = $("html, body"),
    $body = $("body"),
    $doc = $(document),
    $loc = $(location),
    $win = $(window);


  import "./src/account.js";
  import "./src/user.js";
  import "./src/shop.js";
  // etc etc..


  $doc.ready(function() {
    APP.init();
  });
})(jQuery, document, window);
```

When compiling this file Gulp throws the following error:

```
'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

How to use imports within an immediately invoked function expression?

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear: [you cannot do that with ordinary `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). The "dynamic" `import()` that returns a Promise is not supported everywhere yet.

Comment: Can't you use `export` to achieve encapsulation, instead of IIFE?

Comment: What code is in account, user and shop files? After importing how are you planning to consume those files?

Answer (score 1):

Technically `import` can be used within an IIFE. Though to achieve the expected result you can use `import` at the top of a `<script type="module">` then pass the references to the IIFE

```
<script type="module">  
  import a from "./src/account.js";
  import b from "./src/user.js";
  import c from "./src/shop.js";

  (function($, document, window, a, b, c) {
    // do stuff with `a`, `b`, `c`
    var $htmlBody = $("html, body"),
    $body = $("body"),
    $doc = $(document),
    $loc = $(location),
    $win = $(window);
    $doc.ready(function() {
      APP.init();
    });
  })(jQuery, document, window, a, b, c);    
</script>
```